# ReactJS Bootstrap Navbar and Routing not working together

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I am trying to create a simple Webapp using ReactJS, and I wanted to use the `Navbar` provided by React-Bootstrap.

I created a `Navigation.js` file containing a class `Navigation` to separate the `Navbar` and the Routing from the `App.js` file. However, both parts do not seem to work. When I load the page, it is just empty, there is no Navbar. Can anyone spot a mistake?

Navigation.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, Form, FormControl, Button, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Home } from './Page';

class Navigation extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <Navbar>
                        <Navbar.Brand href="/">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
                        <Navbar.Collapse>
                            <Nav className="mr-auto">
                                <NavItem eventkey={1} href="/">
                                    <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
                                </NavItem>
                            </Nav>
                            <Form inline>
                                <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
                                <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
                            </Form>
                        </Navbar.Collapse>
                    </Navbar>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                        <Route render={function () {
                            return <p>Not found</p>
                        }} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Navigation;
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navigation from './components/routing/Navigation';



class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="App">
        <Navigation />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I tried using a `NavItem` containing a `LinkContainer` from `react-router-bootstrap` already, which led to the same result.

Just for completeness, Page.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export const Page = ({ title }) => (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-header">
        <h2>{title}</h2>
      </div>
      <p className="App-intro">
        This is the {title} page.
      </p>
      <p>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </p>
      <p>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
      </p>
      <p>
        <Link to="/settings">Settings</Link>
      </p>
    </div>
);


export const About = (props) => (
    <Page title="About"/>
);

export  const Settings = (props) => (
    <Page title="Settings"/>
);

export const Home = (props) => (
    <Page title="Home"/>
);
```

Answer (score 233, accepted):

First of all, in your snippets it doesn't seem like you're wrapping your code in a `Router`, so you should make sure that you're doing that inside `App` or in `ReactDOM.render`:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>, 
  rootElement
  );
```

Next, your specific problem is that you're rendering react-bootstrap's `Nav.Link` instead of react-router's `Link` component, so the router is not picking up your route changes. Fortunately, react-bootstrap provides a render prop in most of its components to specify which component or element you want to render if you don't want the default. Switch to something like this:

```
import { Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Navigation extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Navbar>
            <Navbar.Brand as={Link} to="/" >React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Collapse>
              <Nav className="mr-auto">
                <NavItem eventkey={1} href="/">
                  <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/" >Home</Nav.Link>
                </NavItem>
              </Nav>
              <Form inline>
                <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
                <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
              </Form>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
          </Navbar>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
            <Route render={function () {
              return <p>Not found</p>
            }} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! the as={Link} and to"..." was what I was missing. It's strange that the bootstrap docs don't mention this at all.

Comment: It looks like this should have `Nav.Item` instead of `NavItem`

Comment: @kugo2006 They're the same component, but yes, it's one less import with `Nav.Item`. Also, the question was about `Nav.Link` and the router, and it looks like I just copied the snippet from OP's question and fixed it, so I didn't do a lot of refactoring :)

Comment: I am wondering where I can find that in the docs. Please somebody paste link to the docs where is that mentioned for reference. How should we know that there is 'as' property?

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/#nav-link-props

Comment: The only issue this fix introduces is that the Navbar no longer collapses when you click a link (not even if collapseOnSelect is present on Navbar).

Answer (score 42):

For those who have a problem with styling `Link` component from `react-router-dom` in react-bootstrap navbar, simply add `className="nav-link"`, like this:

`<Link to="/" className="nav-link">Home</Link>`

instead of

`<Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>`

Comment: I had the same problem too, but I think it's better to use this instead:

`<Nav.Link as={Link} href="/">Home</Nav.Link>` where `{Link}` is the component from `react-router-dom`.

Comment: @MatíasP. If using `as={Link}` you have to replace `href` with `to`

Comment: Thanks. These answers are exactly what I was looking for `<Link to="/" className="nav-link">Home</Link>` OR `<Nav.Link as={Link} to="/" >Home</Nav.Link>`

Answer (score 14):

I hope I'm no late to help some other people trying to solve this.

You can use the NavLink, instead of as={NavLink}. It will render with the same behavior of Link, but will "watch" the router URL to define which link is indeed active:

```
<Nav defaultActiveKey="/bills" as="ul">
      <Nav.Item as="li">
        <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/bills">Dividas</Nav.Link>
      </Nav.Item>
      <Nav.Item as="li">
        <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/other">Em construção</Nav.Link>
      </Nav.Item>
    </Nav>
```

Comment: This does not work: Type '"{Link}"' is not assignable to type 'ElementType<any> | undefined'. Did you mean '"link"'?

Comment: `import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'` , thats the `NavLink` you want to use

Answer (score 2):

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
<App />
</BrowserRouter>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and Navbar.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Container,Navbar,Nav,NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

<Nav className="ml-auto">
<NavItem>   <Link className="nav-link"   to="/">Home</Link> </NavItem> 
<NavItem>   <Link  className="nav-link" to="/about">About</Link> </NavItem> 
<NavItem>    <Link className="nav-link"   to="/contact">Contact</Link> </NavItem> 
</Nav>
```

This resolved the: `<Link>` outside a `<Router>` error for me.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, with react v18 and react-router v6.4, the approach is working for me is a bit different.

To make the links properly work with react-route use **`as={Link}`** in the `Nav.Link` item.

And to make the tabs highlight you need to use **eventKey** as described [in the documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/#nav-link-props): *EventKey is used to determine and control the active state of the parent Nav*

Here is an example.

Notice that the changes also affect the `Navbar.Brand` component.

```
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const AppNavbar = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const activeKey = location.pathname === '/' ? '/projects' : location.pathname;

  return (
    <Navbar expand="lg" className="theme-navbar">
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand as={Link} to="/">
          My Projects
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav activeKey={activeKey} className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link as={Link} eventKey="/projects" to="/projects">
              Projects
            </Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link as={Link} eventKey="/work" to="/work">
              Ongoing Tasks
            </Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. These api's change so quickly everything else is out of date.

Comment: Type '"{Link}"' is not assignable to type 'ElementType<any> | undefined'. Did you mean '"link"'?

Answer (score 1):

Having found myself with a project of non-trivial size, and one that already had jQuery as a dependency I was able to gracefully solve the react-router / react-bootstrap mismatch with an event listener on the `document`.

This has one advantage over other solutions in that it requires no changes to the current markup. However, one may need to write some additional logic guarding the `history.push` call depending on needs. One may also need to expand this to guard for the `target` attribute, e.g. `target="_blank"`.

If jQuery is not desired, one may be able to write a vanilla JS implementation with `document.addEventListener` without much additional effort.

```
// react-router@5
// usage of history may vary depending on version
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

// IIFE scoping jQuery for us
(($) => {
  // Wait for document ready
  $(() => {
    $(document).on('click', '[href]', (event) => {
      // Only target links targeting our application's origin
      if (event.currentTarget.href.indexOf(window.location.origin) === 0) {
        // Prevent standard browser navigation
        event.preventDefault();

        const path = event.currentTarget.href.slice(window.location.origin.length);

        history.push(path);
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);

const Routing = (props) => (
  <Router history={ history }>
    ...
  </Router>
);
```

Answer (score -4):

i think you forgot to include bootstrap css, refer to the stylesheets section of the following doc

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/

or just add the following to ur index.html

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```

Comment: I already included bootstrap css in index.js, thanks for the answer anyways.

Comment: there is nothig to do with css, it's about react router