# I'm getting error about a Target library in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to figure out why my react code won't run. I just set up a router for linking in the Nav but now my render function won't render on any of the pages and I don't know why. Please check out the link to my Code Sandbox for reference [code Sand box](https://codesandbox.io/s/my-portfolio-5n0dv) I would like my file to at least be running. I am using Bootstrap I don't think that is the issue though.

```
Error:(386, 23) TS2583: Cannot find name 'Set'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later.
```

Comment: I think this should help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/39306295/6356919

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your navs are translated into pure `<a href =""/>` and they never use REACT-ROUTER-DOM, luckily react-bootstrap has thought about that

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<Nav className="mr-auto">
   <NavItem href="/">
      <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/" >Home</Nav.Link>
   </NavItem>
</Nav>
```

---

You have a mess on the imports (i hope SandBox messed them up) ==> 
FIX pathsssssssssssssssss
import App from "./components/App";
to
import App from "./App";

at App.js (replace ../src to ./src) 
etcc

Comment: ANDDD 

- your code doesn't run because of bad imports, create a new project and test the  navs in the way i told you

Comment: what is wrong with my imports? can you place your references?

Comment: index.js is in the same directory with App.js, so you shouldn't use
import App from "./components/App" to import it (you would use this if it was in the folder components), when they are in the same folder u use **./**

Did you try my answer ? did it work for your needs ?

Comment: I will try your response give me a second. What page are you referencing above?

Comment: Try on a new project, USE create-react-app if it works feel free to upvote.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843302/reactjs-bootstrap-navbar-and-routing-not-working-together] <== i found some new resources for you too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203139/discussion-between-zachary-blumstein-and-renaldo-balaj).

Comment: that repo did not link